# How to delay expansion of variable in bash if command should be executed on an other machine?

Tags: bash

I have read several threads how to delay a variable expansion by using the eval command, for example but this does not work in my example.

I want to run the following command:

```
 run_on_compute_farm "/usr/bin/time $MAKE -j$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) all"
```

As you can see the command is to be executed on a compute farm and thus on another machine. The problem here is that I want to set the number of jobs,

```
 -j$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
```

But this will evaluate to the number of cpu cores on the machinve that I am sitting on, not on the target.

Is it even possible in bash to delay the evaluation of the variable or the command? Note that run_on_compute_farm command will evaluate and run the string command that it received as argument.

Comment: Replace both `"` by `'`.

Comment: Thanks, this was simpler than i thought

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Cyrus said, you can replace `"` with `'` which will prevent variable expansion.  However, if you require *some* variable expansion, or multiple levels of expansion, then this will not be the right solution.

If in your example you had wanted to expand `$MAKE`, but not perform the `grep`, then the answer I think, is to use `\` to escape the `$`.  So,

```
run_on_compute_farm "/usr/bin/time $MAKE -j\$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) all"
```

will allow `$MAKE` to expand on the local machine, but leave the `grep` for the remote machine to resolve.

You can even nest this strategy, so for example let's get crazy and try this:

```
run_on_compute_farm "run_on_compute_farm \"/usr/bin/time \$MAKE -j\\\$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) all\""
```

Notice that some `"` have been quoted (with `\`) and I've also sent a quoted backslash over as `\\`.  So, on the first remote machine the command executed will be:

run_on_compute_farm "/usr/bin/time $MAKE -j\$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) all"

So, `$MAKE` will be resolved on the first remote, but the `grep` will is still quoted.  This then gets sent to a second machine and becomes:

```
   /usr/bin/time $MAKE -j$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) all
```