# In which order are these instructions executed?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I am using a shell script named *script.sh* that looks like that :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
STRING=$(cat my_string.txt)
${1}
```

In *my_string.txt*, there is only :

```
this_is_my_string
```

When I execute the commands :

```sh
$ STRING="not_my_string"
$ ./script.sh "echo $STRING"
```

The shell prints *not_my_string* instead of *this_is_my_string* and I don’t understand why.
Could you explain me ? And is there any way to force to print the value of the STRING variable which is defined inside the script ?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$STRING` is being expanded before the script is called, which is why `not_my_string` is being assigned.

To delay expansion until after the script is called you should replace `"echo $STRING"` with `'echo $STRING'`.  The single quotes cause the expansion to be delayed.

There is some discussion of delayed expansion here:

[How to delay expansion of variable in bash if command should be executed on an other machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764069/how-to-delay-expansion-of-variable-in-bash-if-command-should-be-executed-on-an-o)

You will also need to replace `${1}` in your script with `eval ${1}`, which will force the string to be executed and expanded.

Comment: When I replace `"echo $STRING"` with `'echo $STRING'` I get `$STRING` as a result and not `this_is_my_string`.

Comment: @Nachdougs Please take a look at the modified response.  If you add `eval` before `${1}` this will force expansion inside of your script.  I tried this on my machine and works the way that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you’re right it works fine. But let’s assume I cannot modify the script (I have to let `${1}` instead of `eval ${1}`). So I tried with `./script.sh "eval echo '$STRING'"`. But it does not work and prints `not_my_string` instead of `this_is_my_string`. Just like if the command eval was executed before the script is called which is something I don’t understand...

Comment: @Nachdougs - I am not aware of how to do this.  You may want to revise the question or ask it as a second question.  It looks like you are trying to pass a command, including a variable reference , as a parameter to a bash script, the referenced variable is expected to be defined inside the script and you cannot control what is in the script.  It's an unusual situation for sure.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ STRING="not_my_string"
$ ./script.sh "echo $STRING"
```

During command execution bash will expand all variables to the values and actually the following command will be executed:
./script.sh "echo not_my_string"

You can use the following:
`./script.sh 'echo $STRING'` to send string as is and `eval "${1}` inside the script to execute argument

Comment: the last line of the script is `${1}` which means the script is going to execute the first argument to the script ... same result will be generated regardless of whether the scirpt is executed or sourced

Comment: Anyway using the same variable name is confusing and not easy to read the code.

Comment: I used the same variable name just for this post as an illustration. This script is a simplified version of the one I really use.

Comment: Ok this thing is really confused me. But now I got what you want to do and updated the answer.